# Simulate mouse click on link for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am writing chrome extension, and I need to click on link next page automatically.
I use `jQuery.noConflict();`  In my Chrome console always throws error -`jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: target.dispatchEvent is not a function.`
This is my code:

```
var dispatchMouseEvent = function (target, var_args) {
var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
e.initEvent.apply(e, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
target.dispatchEvent(e);};

function GoToNextPage() {
var link_nextpage = null;
jQuery(function ($) {
    var pages = $('#results-pagination');
    var next_page = pages.find('.next');
    var link_nextpage = null;
    if (next_page.length) {
        link_nextpage = next_page.find('a');
        dispatchMouseEvent(link_nextpage, 'click', true, true);
    }       
});
}
```

Can you explain to me if it is possible do that, or tell what I did wrong?

Comment: link_nextpage is a jquery object, not a dom element. Either use .trigger or link_nextpage[0] and much more importantly: debug your code!

Comment: link_nextpage[0] works, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said  wOxxOm ,  link_nextpage was a jquery object, not a dom element,  dispatchMouseEvent(link_nextpage[0], 'click', true, true); works good.
That was my stupid mistake.